# What is the event triggered when the command line changes?

Tags: autocmd

I have a function that I'd like to run every time the command line is changed, where by command line I mean the line where text is written when I save a file, get a warning, an error, or echo messages.

I thought `CmdlineChanged` was what I needed, but after saving a file or issuing a command that doesn't exist to get an error my function isn't executed.

Comment: It just happens that the message is printed on the same line as the command line: I don't think there's an event for a message being printed.

Comment: Without a snippet is it hard to help